# Gradient scanning with fmincon

Tags: matlab

I am using fmincon to curve fitting by minimizing residual sum of squares.  When I do not have very many data points, fmincon usually finds local minima that are not close the the global minima which will lead to a good fit.  Is there a way to use a gradient scanning method with fmincon to avoid these local minima?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by gradient scanning... can you add a link? Usually for least-squares problems `lsqnonlin` is a better choice... is there a reason you have to use `fmincon`?

Comment: I agree with Tom on this... fmincon may be a poor choice of algorithm based on your parameters. gradient scanning and finding the proper parameters to a function don't always work hand in hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your problem has local minima, these simple optimization procedures will result in different answers for different initial condition. Try initializing with a reasonable guess, or initialize with multiple random values and choose the one with smallest error.

We can help you better, if you fully describe your problem (What your curve is, and possibly a code snippet.)